# Uncaught Google_Auth_Exception: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client: Unauthorized'

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

can someone help me because I get an error when trying to link my APP with Google Calendar.

I get the error :

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Auth_Exception: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client: Unauthorized' in /web/htdocs/www.assiweb.cloud/home/MyProject/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:132
> Stack trace:
> #0 /web/htdocs/www.assiweb.cloud/home/MyProject/Google/Client.php(128): Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('4/0AX4XfWiN-UCy...', false)
> #1 /web/htdocs/www.assiweb.cloud/home/MyProject/includes/Calendar.php(24): Google_Client->authenticate('4/0AX4XfWiN-UCy...').

the code on Client when I am getting error is:

```
 public function authenticate($code, $crossClient )
{
 $this->authenticated = true;
   return $this->getAuth()->authenticate($code, $crossClient);
   }
```

and the code where I am getting error in Calendar.php (line 24 ) is:

```
 $client->authenticate($_GET['code'],true);
```

These lines of code are not written by me,but i have to resolve this problem and i not know much from Google OAuth,,can someone help me how to resolve it or give me a full working code how to link my app with google account for using then the calendar.

Comment: `invalid_client` sounds like you did not specify a valid client id ...

Comment: @CBroe  dont know how to do that,the code is very complicated and spread on different php files and the senior developer is sick so,.Is there is a way to do this authentication in only one php page ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your not properly applying your authorization to the client. Try checking this.

[Oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

[Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```